# how do i fix this error in python when am making my calculator

Tags: python

I'm getting an error in the `elif op == " / ": print(num1 / num2)`

```
import math
num1 = float(input("Enter number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
op = input("Enter operator")
if op == "+":
  print(num1 + num2)

elif op == "-":
  print(num1 - num2)

  elif op == " / ":
    print(num1 / num2)

    elif op =="*":
      print(num1 * num2)
      else:
        print(enter the right operator -,+,/,*)
```

Comment: if this reflects your indentation, you probably need to make the indentation match the `if` and `elif` above....same for the other `elif` and `else`

Comment: *it is showing error* what is that error? Please add error description which appeared to your question

Comment: what if `num2` is 0? probably need to check before trying to divide by 0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error as text. Not a link, and not an image. Keep in mind that typos as considered off topic per [help], and indentation is very important in Python and yours is incorrect. All if/elif statements need to be aligned

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What error are you getting? It looks like a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `elif op == " / ":` because the indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Is it your indentation that is wrong? because it is not correct in your question.

Correct indenation:

```
import math
num1 = float(input("Enter number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
op = input("Enter operator")
if op == "+":
  print(num1 + num2)
elif op == "-":
  print(num1 - num2)
elif op == " / ":
  print(num1 / num2)
elif op =="*":
  print(num1 * num2)
else:
  print("enter the right operator -,+,/,*")
```

Comment: uhhh i am making a calculator as i mentioned but am getting a error as am new to stackoverflow idk how to upload a picture

Comment: @procode you can copy/paste the error as text

Comment: oh ok here is the error im using replit                      
nvm i cant copy

Comment: @procode you also need to fix your last `print` to have `"`

Comment: wait ill just type it
File "main.py", line 11
    elif op == " / ":
    ^

Comment: here is [replit](https://replit.com/@depperm/simpleCalc#main.py) with above code working

Comment: @depperm OMG THANKS THE ANSWER YOU GAVE ABOVE IS RIGHT can you tell what edits you made to make it the right code sorry am learning python please give any good tutorials too after i finish my this one